# How to create a blur on an iframe?

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

iframe {
  display: block;
  background: #000;
  border: none;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.blur {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blur"> </div>
<iframe class="blur" src="x"></iframe>
```

I'm looking for a way to blur an iframe.

I've been googling for it and I can't find anything. The way I tried to do it was to create a div and to blur that and put it on top. However, they weren't overlaying on top of each other.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Short answer, you can't.

Comment: The `iframe` part of the question is **irrelevant** because you cannot do that even with a simple overlay `div`

Comment: `However, they weren't overlaying ontop of each other.` --> and what you did to make the overlapping?